# Get count of values in json data and create variable based on those for c3 table

Tags: angularjs, count, c3.js

I am trying to create a dynamic donut chart as I don’t know how many variables will be coming in but the dataset will be in the 10,000's with between 1 and 20 variables.

I have got my data into an array as below.

How do I create a `var` for each unique element in the array and its count i.e `var 1 = [sys1, 94]` or similer so they can be used in the  columns and colours config

### Original data

```
res.data[{system:'sys1'},
         {system:'sys1'},
         {system:'sys2'},
         {system:'sys1'},
         {system:'sys3'},
         {system:'sys3'}]
```

### Getting keys

```
var array_elements = []
angular.forEach(res.data, function(value, key){
    if (array_elements.indexOf(value.system) === -1){
        array_elements.push(value.system)        
    }
})

array_elements = ["sys1", "sys2",  "sys3"];
```

### config

```
var donutData = {
    type : 'donut',
    colors: {
  Cats: $.pfPaletteColors.blue,
  Hamsters: $.pfPaletteColors.green,
  Fish: $.pfPaletteColors.orange,
  Dogs: $.pfPaletteColors.red
},
    columns: [
  ['Dogs', 2],
  ['Cats', 2],
  ['Fish', 3],
  ['Hamsters', 1]
],
```

Comment: Where is the value in your data?

Comment: The name is the value sys1, sys2 ..... I need to count how many times they appear in the data and use it as its own key as shown in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var data = [{
  system: 'sys1'
}, {
  system: 'sys1'
}, {
  system: 'sys2'
}, {
  system: 'sys1'
}, {
  system: 'sys3'
}, {
  system: 'sys3'
}];

var tmp = {};
data.forEach(function(x) {
    tmp[x.system] = (tmp[x.system] || 0) + 1;
});

var keys = Object.keys(graphData);

var finalData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var x = [];
    x.push(keys[i]);
    x.push(graphData[keys[i]]);
   finalData.push(x);
}
console.log(finalData);
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/pu8e48cy/2/)